# Selenium chrome driver won't make secure connection

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, https, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to connect securely to a website that has a valid SSL certificate. However, when I connect using Selenium the Chrome browser says the connection is insecure. If I click on the "Not secure" flag in the url bar, it says "Your connection to this site is not secure." If I click on the link below this which says Certificate (Invalid) this opens up a new window with details on the certificate which say "This certificate is valid." How am I supposed to understand this nonsensical discrepancy?

I can connect to some sites securely. For example, connecting to https://www.google.com does not cause the same problem. The site I am having problems with is using a certificate from LetsEncrypt. I really don't know whether this problem is has anything to do with that but what's wrong with the cert or why does Selenium have a problem with it?

Incidentally, I can get Selenium to ignore the error using the "ignore-certificate-errors" flag in the driver options. But this leads to problems down the road when I try to authenticate. So it's not a solution.

The code I am using is basically this with the url and path replaced:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://xxx')
```

Comment: Check the cert by using this site: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The cert passed with an A rating.

Comment: this is pretty odd...  include your webdriver initialization code up to the get() that's causing the issue.  It almost sounds like a caching problem, but not sure why you'd have a cached cert in a Selenium session unless you're using an existing profile.

Comment: I added a code snippet. It's standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was in the url I was passing to the chrome driver. I had mistakenly included www in the url which did not match the url in the ssl cert. I realized how this could cause problems after reading [Chrome says SSL invalid, but certificate is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61049801/chrome-says-ssl-invalid-but-certificate-is-valid) which covers the maddening scenario when your chrome browser tells you the SSL cert is both valid and invalid at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

what works for me in selenium 4.11 is this. pass in your url where i have mine.

```
options = selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
chrome_browser.get('https://demo.seleniumeasy.com/basic-first-form- 
demo.html')
```